# Trying to share image to Facebook using intent crashes Application

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to share an Image to Facebook by using Intent Share approach. However when I do so , the app crashes, this is the code:

```
Bitmap bitmap;
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
//Declared Globally

File out = new File(getFilesDir(), "newImage.jpg");

    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(out.getAbsolutePath());
    ImageView im1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.camOut);
    im1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    im1.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);

 public void shareIt(View view)
{
    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bitmap);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share image using"));
}
```

And this is what I obtain in logcat :

```
> --------- beginning of crash
10-20 19:14:51.404  26669-26669/obx.com.futurister E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: obx.com.futurister, PID: 26669
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
            at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4452)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4447)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure from system
            at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1514)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3917)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3877)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:820)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4200)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4168)
            at obx.com.futurister.CameraTake.shareIt(CameraTake.java:52)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4447)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 4915988 bytes
            at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
            at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:503)
            at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:2657)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1507)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3917)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3877)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:820)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4200)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4168)
            at obx.com.futurister.CameraTake.shareIt(CameraTake.java:52)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4447)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I guess the error is in this line :

```
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bitmap);
```

What's the best way to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass image uri instead of direct bitmap in the line

```
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, <instead pass imageuri>);
```

You could do this like following:

```
    File out = new File(getFilesDir(), "newImage.jpg");
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(out)
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
```

see if it works!

Comment: Thanks, but again when trying to share , it fails in whatsapp and facebook, any idea, why ? :/

Comment: what is the error getting thrown? Same as was it throwing previously?

Comment: No error, opening Facebook and Whatsapp, thats all good, but when clicked to share, unable to ,  wonder if I need to add some other permissions? :/

Comment: `Uri.parse("file:///data/user/0/obx.com.futurister/files/newImage.jpg"));`

Comment: do one thing..try changing to `shareIntent.setType("image/jpg");`..see if that might be a pain point.. jpeg and jpg diff  :(

Comment: I did not understand that, remove that line?

Comment: No no...only change your **jpeg** to **jpg** in that line..mostly won't help..but atleast give it a shot..

Comment: ohh!! i though this might be straightforward..but it isn't..Let me try implementing and finding out the solution..i will edit the post as soon as get it working!

Comment: sure :)  let me know if it does

Comment: I'm surprised no one answered this, but FB is a garbage app and doesn't adhere to the Android share guidelines.  You'd have to install their SDK, for effectively no reason at all, just to share an image.